# Use of pattern attribute in HTML input

Tags: php, html, input, inverse

I have this example for pattern in HTML  `pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9-_. ]{1,30}"`. This means that only letters numbers and `-_.` are allowed, but I want to make a pattern like in the `preg_replace` which allows everything but not `[ <>/\:*?"|]`.

So how can I go with this?

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following:

```
$test = "Hello [<>/\:*?\"|Mister] Jean-Samuels, how are you?_.";
echo preg_replace('/[^\d\w-_. ]+/', '', $test);
```

Output:

```
Hello Mister Jean-Samuels how are you_.
```

**Edit:**

Here is a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NxHr9/2/) of your HTML Pattern.

HTML:

```
<input title='Enter anything but <, >, /, \, :, *, ?, ", |' 
type='text' 
pattern='[^<>\/\\:*?"|]{1,30}' required />
```

Comment: HI everyone, tahnks for the answers but i'm not talking about a regex in php code i'm talking about putting a regex in the HTML pattern i tried before to use the char ^ to exclue some letters but it didint worked in HTML pattern ...

Answer (score 0):

The `^` operator in a character class will negate the entire class, so you can use:

```
[^<>/\:*?"|]
```

Which will match everything *except* those characters inside the character class. Keep in mind that you might have to escape the `"` if the surrounding quotes for the `pattern` attribute are `"` as well.

Comment: I thought that some of this characters have to be escaped to got them to work.

Comment: @Hexodus deoends on the context, really. But yes the `"` will probably need to be escaped. If the surrounding quotes are `"`.

Answer (score 0):

Negative character classes in regex are done like this: `[^characters to exclude]`

Note the `^` just inside the `[`, that's what makes it a negative.

That said, you should probably stick with what you have, otherwise you'll get someone like me trying to enter ヴィックサ for a name :p

Comment: But what if my name is ヴィックサ? :( (It isn't)